# Преобразование русской даты в тип datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, locale

При попытке перевода колонки в формат 'data' выдает ошибку : **ParserError: Unknown string format: 18-апр-2022**
Используемый код: `doh_total['DTRNCREATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(doh_total['DTRNCREATE'])`
Как выглядят данные в колонке 'DTRNCREATE' :

```
array(['18-апр-2022', '20-апр-2022', '11-апр-2022', '21-апр-2022',
       '02-апр-2022', '15-апр-2022', '12-апр-2022', '28-апр-2022',
       '06-апр-2022', '16-апр-2022', '22-апр-2022', '26-апр-2022',
       '14-апр-2022', '30-апр-2022', '25-апр-2022', '29-апр-2022',
       '09-апр-2022', '07-апр-2022', '19-апр-2022', '08-апр-2022',
       '27-апр-2022', '04-апр-2022', '01-апр-2022', '13-апр-2022',
       '23-апр-2022', '05-апр-2022'], dtype=object)
```

Как перевести тип данных object в datetime?

Answer (score 3):

pandas не понимает по умолчанию не англоязычную дату. поэтому, выставляйте локаль и вперёд.

```
import pandas as pd
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')

df = pd.DataFrame(['18-апр-2022', '20-апр-2022', '11-апр-2022', '21-апр-2022',
       '02-апр-2022', '15-апр-2022', '12-апр-2022', '28-апр-2022',
       '06-апр-2022', '16-апр-2022', '22-апр-2022', '26-апр-2022',
       '14-апр-2022', '30-апр-2022', '25-апр-2022', '29-апр-2022',
       '09-апр-2022', '07-апр-2022', '19-апр-2022', '08-апр-2022',
       '27-апр-2022', '04-апр-2022', '01-апр-2022', '13-апр-2022',
       '23-апр-2022', '05-апр-2022'], columns = ['DTRNCREATE'])

df["DTRNCREATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DTRNCREATE"], format="%d-%b-%Y")
print(df)
print(df.info())
```

```
   DTRNCREATE
0  2022-04-18
1  2022-04-20
2  2022-04-11
3  2022-04-21
4  2022-04-02
5  2022-04-15
6  2022-04-12
7  2022-04-28
8  2022-04-06
9  2022-04-16
10 2022-04-22
11 2022-04-26
12 2022-04-14
13 2022-04-30
14 2022-04-25
15 2022-04-29
16 2022-04-09
17 2022-04-07
18 2022-04-19
19 2022-04-08
20 2022-04-27
21 2022-04-04
22 2022-04-01
23 2022-04-13
24 2022-04-23
25 2022-04-05
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 26 entries, 0 to 25
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   DTRNCREATE  26 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 336.0 bytes
None
```

Comment: работаю в Jupyter Notebook, выдает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки получилось, но вместо предложения  `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')` попробовал

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'ru_RU.utf8' и получилось :)
```

Comment: не понятно, что у вас получилось. пустая локаль или что?